# Return original data type (Collection) from another application using GuzzleClient in Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections, return-type, guzzle

I have a problem when retrieve the returned data from another application using GuzzleClient.
For example, in the First Application, I call to Second application `test` function to get the returned data as Collective data type, however I have not idea how to do that. I try to json_decode the response in `call_another_server` function but it will become array, if i not using json_decode, it will just return as a string.

**First Application**

```
public function call_another_server()
{
  $client = new GuzzleClient();
  $url = 'http://127.0.0.1:1111/testing'; ##### This url will call to second application@test() function
  $response  = $client->request('GET', $url);

  $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);//retrieve the response data and decode it as array
  dd($response);
}
```

**Second Application**

```
public function test()
{
    $array = ["1" => "one", "2" => "two"];
    return (collect($array)); ##### return as collective
}
```

**Returned Result** (in `call_another_server`, dd($response) )

[image]

***Expected Result*** ( returned as Collection )

[image]

Can anyone can guide me how to return as my expected result in `call_another_server` function? I know I can manipulate the response in `call_another_server` using collect helper to make the response become Collection type. But I hope I can just retrieve the original data type from `test` function.
Any guidance and suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not retrieve the Collection you want that way. Because when you `return (collect($array))` your app is casting your Collection to array, and then convert it to json (for json response).

To avoid casting to array you can **serialize your Collection**, and then send the serialized data (being string now) as response.

So :

**1. First Application**

```
public function call_another_server()
{
  [...]

  $data = unserialize($response->getBody()->getContents());//unserialize retrieved data
  dd($data);
}
```

**2. Second Application**

```
public function test()
{
    [...]
    return serialize(__YOUR_COLLECTION_HERE__); // return serialized collection
}
```

BUT WARNING :

- First: Take note of warnings about unserializing foreign data (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

> ... Do not pass untrusted user input to unserialize() ...

- Second: to properly unserialize received data, you have in the two apps the same Collection class (for example `Illuminate\Support\Collection`). Also valid for any object class contained in the collection data eventually.

Comment: Hello @Olivier, thanks bro for your suggestion and warning, I would mark your answer as accepted. Appreciated your help brother